# How to add type to my classes?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Shelf {

  private List<type> shelf = new ArrayList<>();

  public void addItem(type item) {
    shelf.add(item);
  }

  public type removeItem(int i) {
    type output = shelf.get(i);
    shelf.remove(i);
    return output;
  }

}


public class testclass {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Shelf<String> shelf = new Shelf();
    String book = "Books";
    shelf.addItem(book);
    System.out.println(shelf.removeItem(0));

  }



}
```

I'm trying to find out how I am able to initialize a type when I create a class so above example would work?

In shelf class whereever I have type, thats the type that the program would use.

Comment: public class Shelf<T> { private List<T> shelf = new ArrayList<>(); ...}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a type as a generic by suffixing the type name with a list of type parameters:

```
public class Shelf<type> {
    ...
}
```

Now, anywhere inside of the `Shelf` class, you can refer to `type` whenever you want to refer to the type that the client specifies in angle braces.

(Customarily, you'd give that placeholder a name whose first letter was capitalized, like `Type`, to make clear that it's a type name.)

Answer (score 1):

A *type parameter* can be defined as follows:

```
public class Shelf<type> {
    ...
}
```

The type parameter section follows the class name and is delimited by angle brackets (`<` and `>`).

A type variable can be any non-primitive type you specify: any class type, any interface type, any array type, or even another type variable.

---

When you instantiate a `Shelf`, you indicate its type:

```
Shelf<String> shelf = new Shelf<>();
shelf.addItem("a string goes here");
```

```
Shelf<Integer> shelf = new Shelf<>();
shelf.addItem(42);
```

---

There are some conventions about the type parameter names. Instead of `type` you should use `T`:

```
public class Shelf<T> {
    ...
}
```

See this quote from [The Java Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html) from Oracle (highlight is mine):

> By convention, type parameter names are single, **uppercase letters**.
>   This stands in sharp contrast to the variable [naming](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html#naming) conventions that
>   you already know about, and with good reason: Without this convention,
>   it would be difficult to tell the difference between a type variable
>   and an ordinary class or interface name.
>
> The most commonly used type parameter names are:
>
> - `E` - Element (used extensively by the Java Collections Framework)
> - `K` - Key
> - `N` - Number
> - `T` - Type
> - `V` - Value
> - `S`, `U`, `V` etc. - 2nd, 3rd, 4th types